# Is dnsmasq using port 53 a vulnerability?

Tags: networking, linux, dns, nmap, dnsmasq

I ran an nmap scan on my home network and linux machine. There were a few suspicious ports open so I used the command `netstat -tanp|grep LISTEN` to investigate further. The output was that dnsmasq is listening on port 53. Why when I run the command `apt-get remove dnsmasq` linux is telling me that dnsmasq is not installed. Is this suspicious? How do I find out who is running dnsmasq on port 53? I've cd into the directory in which dnsmasq is located and its telling me its not installed.

Comment: "dnsmasq is listening on port 53" It is then important to know on which IP address it is listening. If it is listening on `127.0.0.1` and/or `::1`, then there is no vulnerability as this is localhost. If it is listening on the box external IP or `0.0.0.0` which means any IP (more precisely all IPs of the box), then indeed it may be reachable from outside... but this also depends if any firewall is running on the box and filtering DNS traffic or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...  when I run the command apt-get remove dnsmasq"*

`apt-get remove` requires the package name, not a name of a program. On Debian/Ubuntu it might be `dmasq-base` instead

> How do I find out who is running dnsmasq on port 53?

Look at the pid of the process from the netstat output and then check where this binary points to, i.e.

```
# netstat -tnlp
...
tcp        0      0 172.16.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1544/dnsmasq

# ls -l /proc/1544/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 12 07:51 /proc/1544/exe -> /usr/sbin/dnsmasq
```

Then check which package this belongs to:

```
# dpkg -S /usr/sbin/dnsmasq
dnsmasq-base: /usr/sbin/dnsmasq
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue

Comment: @i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i Then please consider marking the anwer as accepted (checkmark under the votes counts). This shows others that your question got a usable answer.